# Vuetify toolbar and centered block makes the page scrollable

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

As the title says, my page is scrollable when it actually should not.

What I use is a toolbar combined with a centered card. The v-container is fill-height and the layout inside it is centered. The v-toolbar has an attribute 'app', which gives the v-content top-padding that is based on the toolbar height. Because of this padding, the whole page is scrollable when it should not be. Even when everything fits, it only should be scrollable when the screen height is smaller than the card itself. Also, the attribute 'app' is needed to prevent the card showing under the toolbar when the screen is small in height.

Code:

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-toolbar dark fixed app>
            <v-toolbar-title>Toolbar something</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-content>
            <v-container fluid fill-height>
                <v-layout justify-center align-center>
                <v-flex text-xs-center>
                    <v-card>
                        <v-card-text>HUH <br /> <br /> <br /> Centered</v-card-text>
                    </v-card>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </v-content>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Note: Somehow I cannot reproduce this problem in CodePen, however, I can reproduce it on a blank Vue project.

Comment: Have you tried removing `fill-height`?

Comment: Yes, but when fill-height is not used, the block will not be centered. I am also using the latest version of Vue (2.6.9) and Vuetify (1.5.6)

Comment: That is not the right way of centralizing them. `fill-height` is used to "Making sure that col element height is filled with parent and child" . You can use `<v-layout column wrap justify-center align-center>` to centralize and remove the `fill-height`

Comment: Another way of centralizing the card```<v-layout>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>  <v-card></v-card><v-flex><v-layout>```

Comment: When I apply your changes (both of them), the block is not centered vertically.

Comment: @Unknown Have you tried removing the padding from the toolbar by doing: `class="pt-0"`?

Comment: @EvanBechtol Yes, I have. But like I said in my question, I cannot remove the top padding because it is to prevent the card showing under the toolbar when the screen is smaller in height.

Comment: Are you able to use the dev tools to see which element is actually causing the scrollbar to appear? It seems unlikely that it would be related to the toolbar. I have been trying to replicate this on my environment, and cannot. I copy/pasted your exact code into a blank project

Comment: @EvanBechtol I will look into that later. In Liveweave I can reproduce the problem https://liveweave.com/cDRGwj

Comment: Anyone found a solution?

Comment: @Robofan yes see my answer below, that was the stupid solution for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the base page when rendering Vue